# AWS Cloudformation Deleted resource from console now serverless updates are failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm learning serverless cloudformation deployments and have corrupted my cloudformation stack. I ended up creating an export from one of my resource deployments and imported it into another resource - all within the same stack. That is where my trouble started. I unsuccessfully tried to redeploy a few different ways to get around my circular import. Then I had the bright idea to just go into the console and delete the listener that was causing all the trouble. Bad idea. Now I am stuck in a state of update_rollback_complete because the resource that I deleted is not there. I created the exact resource via the console but it of course has a different ARN. I had assumed that I could just delete the stack but now all of my deletes fail.

Now that I have completely corrupted my stack how can I remove it? I'd like to burn my corrupted stack to the ground and completely start over. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you delete from the root stack via mgmt console, after the first delete fail it should then give you an option to delete and retain resources. Use this option to retain the listener so that the stack delete option skips the resource.

Comment: I'm not seeing an option to delete or retain resources. How do I access that option? I try to delete it it fails and reverts back to update_rollback_complete.